# Is there a way in Google Sheets to extract country level codes (if available) from domains?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of domains and I want to extract country codes from the URLs, if they are available. Is there a formula that I can use in Google sheets or Excel to quickly get this?

Expected output from the domains are mentioned below:

- mk.ru -> ru
- news.yahoo.co.jp -> jp
- nabdn.com -> NA
- 247.libero.it -> it
- zazoom.it -> it
- news.goo.ne.jp -> jp
- tw.news.yahoo.com -> tw
- topics.smt.docomo.ne.jp -> jp
- excite.co.jp -> jp

I tried to split the columns but it is not consistent and is manual to collate the country codes.

Comment: You'd need a rule here: Would country-code always be two letters at the end (or if not at end, at the start) of a string if applicable?

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
=ArrayFormula(LAMBDA(x,y, IF(x<>"com",x,IF(LEN(y)=2,y,NA())))
 (BYROW(A2:A, LAMBDA(x, IF(x="",,
  INDEX(SPLIT(x,"."), ,COLUMNS(SPLIT(x,".")))))),
  BYROW(A2:A, LAMBDA(x, IF(x="",,INDEX(SPLIT(x,"."), ,1))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @JvdV the answer is updaated.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A9, "\b(co|ne|mk)\b", " "), "\b.{2}\b"))
```

[image]

Comment: `=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "\.(.+)$"))` @Player0 where is the problem here?

Comment: @Osm with that you will return everything from after the first dot to the end